# How to print R matrix from sprintf

Tags: r, printf

For the following matrix :

```
> mat
             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
[2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17
[3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17
```

Consider the following `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("proj: %s", mat)
```

The output is:

```
print(sprintf("proj: %s", mat))
[1] "proj: 8.32667268468867e-17"  "proj: 2.77555756156289e-17"
[3] "proj: 0"                     "proj: 5.55111512312578e-17"
[5] "proj: 3.67761376907083e-16"  "proj: -2.77555756156289e-17"
[7] "proj: 5.55111512312578e-17"  "proj: -5.55111512312578e-17"
[9] "proj: 5.55111512312578e-17"
```

What we want is the same output as just `mat` but with the

> "proj: "

message prepended. Specifically:

```
proj:             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
[2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17
[3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17
```

How to use sprintf to achieve that?

**UPDATE**  From answer from Sven an attempt to create a function is here:

```
printmat <- function(mat) {
  out <- capture.output(mat)
  out[1] <- paste0("proj:", out[1])
  paste(out, collapse = "\n")
}
```

Here is output: single line (would be better 4 lines like original):

```
print(printmat(mat))

[1] "proj:             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]\n[1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17\n[2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17\n[3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17"
```

**Another update**  A different answer - from Richard Scriven - uses `print.listof(list)`.  Here is a function incorporating the `capture.output`.  This solution however suffers from not allowing flexible message: it is hardcoded to `"proj"`:

```
printmat <- function(mat) {
  out <- capture.output(print.listof(list(proj = mat)))
}
```

Here is the output: it is *close* .. but notice we do not have choice of changing `"proj"` to something else:

```
   print(printmat(mat))

[1] "proj :"
[2] "             [,1]          [,2]          [,3]"
[3] "[1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17"
[4] "[2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17"
[5] "[3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17"
[6] ""
```

**Third update**   I have added a flexible "message/matrix name" parameter. However `sprintf` prepends it to EVERY line of the output:

```
printmat <- function(msg, mat) {
  out <- capture.output(print.listof(list(mat)))
  sprintf("%s: %s", msg, out)
}
```

Here is a test:

```
> print(printmat("mymat", mat))
[1] "mymat: Component 1 :"
[2] "mymat:              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]"
[3] "mymat: [1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17"
[4] "mymat: [2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17"
[5] "mymat: [3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17"
[6] "mymat:
```

So is there a way to suppress the **`sprintf`** from prefixing *every* line with the message?

Comment: The reason that "sprintf prefixes every line ..." is called recycling: `sprintf( fmt, "str", 1:3 )` is the same, after recycling, as `sprintf( fmt, list("str", "str", "str" ), 1:3 )` -- strange but true. `paste` does this too; I haven't figured out how to turn it off. (`??recycle` is funny.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sprintf()` you will convert the entire matrix into characters, making it more difficult to access their numeric values later.

Instead, you could use the `listof` class and then you can still access all the numeric values. First put the matrix (or matrices) into a named list. Here's a quick peek at how it would look.

```
m <- structure(c(8.326673e-17, 2.775558e-17, 0, 5.551115e-17, 3.677614e-16, 
-2.775558e-17, 5.551115e-17, -5.551115e-17, 5.551115e-17), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L))

print.listof(list(proj = m))
# proj :
#              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
# [1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
# [2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17
# [3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17
```

To make this so that we don't need to call `print.listof()`, we can add the `listof` class to a list containing `m`. Then it will print like you want and you can also still access the matrix values unchanged.

```
mm <- list(proj = m)
class(mm) <- "listof"
mm
# proj :
#              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
# [1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
# [2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17
# [3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17    
mm$proj[1,]
# [1] 8.326673e-17 5.551115e-17 5.551115e-17
```

You can change the first line at any time simply by changing the names of `mm`

```
setNames(mm, "PROJ")
# PROJ :
#              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
# [1,] 8.326673e-17  5.551115e-17  5.551115e-17
# [2,] 2.775558e-17  3.677614e-16 -5.551115e-17
# [3,] 0.000000e+00 -2.775558e-17  5.551115e-17
```

Finally, here's how we can use all this information as a function:

```
f <- function(mat, nm) {
    x <- setNames(list(mat), nm)
    class(x) <- "listof"
    x
}

f(m, "proj")
f(m, "project 1")
```

Comment: This has potential. But I need to vary the "proj" by the different matrix names: can not always be/hardcode to "proj".  I will update the OP with a function including the partial solution from this answer in a moment

Comment: The OP was updated with a function incorporating this answer together with Sven's capture.output. But as noted the configurable message/matrix name is still missing.

Comment: re: not use capture.output.  OK - however please clarify how to set the output name: the above commentary on names(mm) and class(mm) are not enough for me yet.

Comment: OK, i am updating my function now, will get back in several mins

Comment: You *just* beat me to the function part. Thanks.

Comment: @javadba - no problem, this one was fun

Comment: Can you explain the class(x) <- "listof" :  it seems R has a different syntax for  class/method decoration than  other languages

Comment: `class(x) <- "listof"` is the same as `x <- "class<-"(x, "listof")`.  It's called a replacement function, as it makes assignment to the class of `x` as a function.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Very nice.  How did you dig this ? :-)

Comment: @akrun - thanks :)  I discovered this class while playing around with `print.by` and other print methods because I've been working on a function that uses `ls.str`.  So basically by accident.  haha

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with `capture.output`:

```
# an example matrix
mat <- matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3)

# standard print output
out <- capture.output(mat)
# modify first line
out[1] <- paste0("proj:", out[1])
# print modified version
cat(paste(out, collapse = "\n"))
```

The output:

```
proj:          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.8760935 -0.8395728 -1.569009
[2,] 0.2660100 -2.2364285 -1.872737
[3,] 0.4996019 -0.6997563 -2.136702
```

---

As a function:

```
printmat <- function(mat) {
  out <- capture.output(mat)
  out[1] <- paste0("proj:", out[1])
  cat(paste(out, collapse = "\n"))
}


printmat(mat)
```

Comment: great, I am a relative newbie to R and learnt 3 thing here; capture.output, paste0, and collapse. I will update OP on incorporating into a function.

Comment: Seems to be some infinite recursion here.  See the function in OP

Comment: @javadba I seems that your syntax is wrong. I added a function to my answer.

Comment: OK yes you have corrected the missing parameter.  Can you fix the output to be on 4 lines like the original instead of just one?  See the updated OP.

Comment: I do not recall what the exact output was with cat - but it was not as specified.